# Limit amount of products that can be added from a category to Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, addition, woocommerce, cart

**Hi There, does anybody know how to limit the amount of products that can bee added from a specific Product Category in WooCommerce.**

I'm working on a tour website were they offer tour packages. So think of a Tour Package as a Product Category. The products in there would be the tours. The client only wants a limited number of tours to be added from a Product category.

Example, 10 tours in a Category, the package only allows for 5 tours to be selected.

Some help would be greatly appreciated. I have searched the net and looked at plugins but noooooo luck.

Thanks
Shaun!!!

Comment: A plugin called "Min and Max Purchase for WooCommerce" that allows you to set Max purchase rules for items (there is aro version as well).

Answer (score 1):

Min / Max is limited to simple products.

Example I have 2 free products. An 8x10 photo and a 5x7 photo. I want to allow the customer to have 2 free photos.

I can restrict each product to 2, but that would allow them to buy 4 photos.
Or I could restrict each product to 1, but that would not allow them to buy 2 8x10s or 2 5x7s.

You might think (as I did) that if you group the products you could restrict to 2 from the group . . . but it does not do this unfortunately.

It will allow you to add to a category and only allow items to be purchased in "a group of . . . ".  This means you could add all your tours to a category, and insist that tours be purchased in groups of 5. IOW they can't buy 4 or they can't buy 6, they can only buy 5. That might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is Maximum Purchase for Woo Commerce. There is also a pro version that offers a little more functionality. They are available [here](http://www.varktech.com/woocommerce/min-and-max-purchase-for-woocommerce/). This solved a few complicated issues for me in terms of minimum and maximum cart requirements. And the dev is very helpful.